# Bulk insert with Sugar ORM not working

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, sugarorm

I have a databese in my Android app which must contain some predefined Data when the App gets installed. To do this I am trying to do "Bulk Insert" using Sugar ORM. It seems the example code in SugarORM docs has some mistakes both in Syntax and Implementation or it is not complete! Does anyone know the practical way to insert bulk data?

Doc code:

```
List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
books.add(new Book("isbn123", "Title here", "2nd edition"))
books.add(new Book("isbn456", "Title here 2", "3nd edition"))
books.add(new Book("isbn789", "Title here 3", "4nd edition"))
SugarRecord.saveInTx(books);
```

It seems there is no saveInTx in SugarRecord class!

My code:

```
import com.orm.SugarRecord;
import com.orm.dsl.Table;
import com.orm.dsl.Unique;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


@Table()
public class Foods extends SugarRecord{
    @Unique
    private String foodName;
    private String calorie;

    public Foods(String foodName, String calorie) {
        this.foodName = foodName;
        this.calorie = calorie;
    }

    public void putData(){
    List<Foods> foods = new ArrayList<>();
    foods.add(new Foods("Lamb Chops", "12"));
    foods.add(new Foods("Onion", "32"));
    foods.add(new Foods("Apple", "43"));
    SugarRecord.saveInTx(foods);    
}
}
```

Comment: have to tried this if so post your code also?

Comment: Just added. Please recheck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't say like *It seems there is no saveInTx in SugarRecord class!*, there is a methods that work in `SugarRecord` class i.e.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation") 
    public static <T> void saveInTx(Collection<T> objects) { 
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getSugarContext().getSugarDb().getDB(); 
        try { 
            sqLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(); 
            sqLiteDatabase.setLockingEnabled(false); 
            for (T object: objects) { 
                save(object); 
            } 
            sqLiteDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful(); 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            Log.i("Sugar", "Error in saving in transaction " + e.getMessage()); 
        } finally { 
            sqLiteDatabase.endTransaction(); 
            sqLiteDatabase.setLockingEnabled(true); 
        } 
    }
```

I have tried this, it works fine. Just **Filter your Logcat with "Sugar" keyword** while saving record. You will find something like  `I/Sugar: Foods saved : 1` 
 You can also see the count you have added in the table with:

```
  long foodCount= SugarRecord.count(Foods.class);
  Log.i("Foods", "Foods " + foodCount);
```

So if you are not getting data via `SugarRecord.listAll(oods.class)`,

> **So the only problem is you just miss an empty constructor at the model class**

try to add empty constructor and try again. delete your previous data also.

Hope it will help!!!